# Can't update table. Showing "identifier of an instance altered from X to Y"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, mapstruct

I want to update: **sampleShipmentId**, **sampleId**, **description** in my **SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity**
I’m using Spring Boot, Java 17, Hibernate, JPA, MapStruct and Lombok.
Error message:

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: identifier of an
> instance of domain.sampleshipment.persistence.SampleShipmentEntity was
> altered from 3 to 1; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of
> domain.sampleshipment.persistence.SampleShipmentEntity was altered
> from 3 to 1]

```
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesUpdateUseCase {
  private final SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesStore store;
  private final DtoMapper mapper;

  public SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesUpdateResponse execute(long id, SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesUpdateRequest updateRequest) {
    SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity = store.load(id, IncludeFilter.EXCLUDE);
    mapper.fromUpdateRequest(updateRequest, sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity);
    sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity = store.save(sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity);
    return mapper.toUpdateResponse(sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity);
  }

  @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
  interface DtoMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "sampleShipment.id", source = "sampleShipmentId")
    @Mapping(target = "sample.id", source = "sampleId")
    void fromUpdateRequest(SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesUpdateRequest updateRequest,
                                                      @MappingTarget SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity);

    @Mapping(source = "sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity.sampleShipment.id", target = "sampleShipmentId")
    @Mapping(source = "sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity.sample.id", target = "sampleId")
    SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesUpdateResponse toUpdateResponse(SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity);
  }
}


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesUpdateRequest {
  private long sampleShipmentId;
  private long sampleId;
  private String description;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "sample_shipment_discrepancies")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  @ToString.Include
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "sample_shipment_id", nullable = false)
  private SampleShipmentEntity sampleShipment; // it has id that I want to map

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "sample_id")
  private SampleEntity sample;// it has id that I want to map

  @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
  @ToString.Include
  private String description;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesUpdateResponse {
  private long id;
  private long sampleShipmentId;
  private long sampleId;
  private String description;
}


@PutMapping("/{id}")
public SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesUpdateResponse update(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesUpdateRequest updateRequest) {
  return sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesUpdateUseCase.execute(id, updateRequest);
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoTransactional
class SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesStoreAdapter implements SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesStore {
  private final SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesRepository repository;

   @Override
  public SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity load(final long id, IncludeFilter deleted) {
    Specification<SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity> spec = SpecificationHelper.create(FilterBuilder.equal("id", id));
    spec = SpecificationHelper.addDeletedFilter(spec, deleted);
    return repository.findOne(spec).orElseThrow(SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesNotFoundException::new);
  }

  @Override
  public SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity save(final SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity) {
    return repository.save(sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity);
  }


  @Repository
  interface SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesRepository extends JpaRepository<SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity, Long>,
      JpaSpecificationExecutor<SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity> {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote my method in SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesUpdateUseCase to set it directly. I still don't understand what is the problem. And why MapStruct can't automatically map it properly.

```
  public SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesUpdateResponse execute(long id, SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesUpdateRequest updateRequest) {
    SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity = sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesStore.load(id, IncludeFilter.EXCLUDE);
    mapper.fromUpdateRequest(updateRequest, sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity);
    sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity.setSampleShipment(sampleShipmentStore.load(updateRequest.getSampleShipmentId()));
    sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity.setSample(sampleRepository.findById(updateRequest.getSampleId())
        .orElseThrow(SampleNotFoundException::new));
    SampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity updatedSampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity =
        sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesStore.save(sampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity);
    return mapper.toUpdateResponse(updatedSampleShipmentDiscrepanciesEntity);
  }
```

Comment: Sometimes I think that stackoverflow is dead :(